# How to disable automatic linting of imported classes from modules?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In my project, I'm importing a series of different other modules/classes, for instance like this:

```
from my_project.filesystem import create_dir
from my_project.filesystem import file_size
from my_project.hashing import hash_from_file
from my_project.multiprocessing import max_workers_for
from my_project.multiprocessing import multiprocessing
```

When saving the file, [Python extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python) automatically is linting those lines into:

```
from my_project.filesystem import create_dir, file_size
from my_project.hashing import hash_from_file
from my_project.multiprocessing import max_workers_for, multiprocessing
```

In settings, I have tried disabling auto linting:

```
{
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": false,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=all"
    ]
}
```

For clarity, I prefer to have my imports separate, but now I'm faced with a daunting task to "fix the fix" before committing any changes.

Is there a way to disable this feature (bar disabling the whole extension, which works but removes other features of the extension which I'd prefer to continue using)?

Comment: Try to look for options like "formatter" or "sort imports". A linter does not modify the code AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your imports get sorted by [`isort`](https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort). You might be able to solve the issue by passing a custom argument to it. The "force_single_line" option mentioned [here](https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort/wiki/isort-Settings#full-reference-of-isort-settings) seems to be what you want. To pass this configuration option to isort, add the following line to your vs code config:

`"python.sortImports.args": ["-sl"]`

Let me know if that solves the issue.

Comment: This was exactly the issue here. By adding the parameters it has ceased to modify my imports. Thank you.